# Parsing a String in Java to extract data

Tags: java, string, parsing

Quick question about how to parse a string in java:

I have this string: `"name: Banana cake, made with sugar, glycemicindex: 47"` and I am trying to extract (1) the string after `"name:"` and before the `", glycemicindex: 47"` (so the string `"Banana cake, made with sugar"`) and (2) the string after `"glycemicindex:"` (so the string `47`).

Essentially I have a bunch of data points that are in the format `"name: [name data], glycemicindex: [glycemicindex data]"`, and I want to extract both the name data and glycemicindex data and store them in a list.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thank you! I appreciate any help :)

Comment: I have an idea - use regex.

Comment: Why not simply split by `,` and after by `:`...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie According to the example, `,` can be a part of value so you cannot use that as field delimiter.

Comment: by any chance , are u getting this string as JSON response ??

Answer (score 5):

If this is meant to be quick&dirty hack, you can use regular expressions:

```
String text = "name: Banana cake, made with sugar, glycemicindex: 47";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name: (.*) glycemicindex: (\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

If this is meant to be a part of robust system, you should obtain the exact specification of this format and parse it accordingly (not necessarily with regex).

Answer (score 0):

Not that the others are wrong, just an alternate way to achieve the same -

provided that the data format is `name:<data1>, glycemicindex:<data2>`

```
String message="name: Banana cake, made with sugar, glycemicindex: 47";
String []splits = message.split(", glycemicindex:");
String name = (splits[0].replace("name:","").trim());
String glycemicIndex = splits[1].trim();
```